# Json undefined issue

Tags: google-apps-script, trello

I am having an issue with my json parsing where I keep getting undefined when i try to loop through my json data.

Here is the sample Json code that keeps returning undefined:

```
 [{"id":"5f99b552b2c25b37596871e3","value":{"number":"1"},"idCustomField":"5f998faf4bb46e574ac28514","idModel":"5f907f344b88092b1d0e03d1","modelType":"card"}]
```

I am using the following to get the payload and then parse it:

```
        var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "cards/" + card.id + "/customFieldItems?"+ key_and_token);  
        customfielditems = JSON.parse(response2.getContentText()).actions;
```

When I try to loop through my object I get an undefined value for my object.  Loop listed below:

```
for (var m=0; m < customfielditems.length; m++) {

customfielditemid = customfielditems[m].value

}
```

Mind you I don't even get to the point where I provide a value.  I get an error indicating ".length" is undefined.  Focusing the object, the object itself (customfielditems) is also undefined even after its parsed.

Would love links or suggestions on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: By guessing your response value from the API,I suggested a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Could you please reference what URL are you trying to fetch, and provide the corresponding reference docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the URL of your script, I thought that you might be using ["Get Custom Field Items for a Card"](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/api-group-cards/#api-cards-id-customfielditems-get). When the official document of "Get Custom Field Items for a Card" is seen, it seems that the response value is `Array<CustomFieldItems>`. And the sample response value is as follows.

```
[
  {
    "id": "5abbe4b7ddc1b351ef961414",
    "value": {
      "checked": "true"
    },
    "idCustomField": "5abbe4b7ddc1b351ef961414",
    "idModel": "5abbe4b7ddc1b351ef961414",
    "modelType": "card"
  }
]
```

From above response value, I understood that your `response2.getContentText()` is the value of `[{"id":"5f99b552b2c25b37596871e3","value":{"number":"1"},"idCustomField":"5f998faf4bb46e574ac28514","idModel":"5f907f344b88092b1d0e03d1","modelType":"card"}]` in your question. If my understanding is correct, in this case, `customfielditems` of `customfielditems = JSON.parse(response2.getContentText()).actions;` is `undefined`. I thoutht that the reason of your issue is due to this.

When you want to retrieve `value` from the response value, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "cards/" + card.id + "/customFieldItems?"+ key_and_token);
customfielditems = JSON.parse(response2.getContentText());

for (var m=0; m < customfielditems.length; m++) {
  customfielditemid = customfielditems[m].value;
}
```

- When you want to retrieve the value of `1` of `{"number":"1"}`, please modify `customfielditemid = customfielditems[m].value;` as follows.

  ```
    customfielditemid = Object.values(customfielditems[m].value); // or Object.values(customfielditems[m].value)[0];
  ```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that you have already been able to use the API using `url + "cards/" + card.id + "/customFieldItems?"+ key_and_token`. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Get Custom Field Items for a Card](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/api-group-cards/#api-cards-id-customfielditems-get)

Comment: Removing the .action after the JSON.parse worked and it's working great appreciate your help here.

Comment: @Maxamis4 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.